# LinkButton : Abrir link em uma nova janela (Botão direito do Mouse)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de eu abrir uma nova aba clicando com o botão direito, ou com botão do meio do mouse...

Estou utilizando o "`LinkButton`" porém o comando ocorre dentro de um `OnItemCommand="ListaMenu_ItemCommand`".
Aspx :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ListaMenu" runat="server" 
                                 OnItemCommand="ListaMenu_ItemCommand">
                                 <ItemTemplate>                                      
                                            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LknMenu" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NOMTIPPRO").ToString()%>' ToolTip ='<%#Eval("CODTIPPRO").ToString()%>' target="_blank"> 
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                            </li>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

Aspx.cs :

```
protected void ListaMenu_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkId = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LknMenu");
    Response.Redirect("~/KnPesquisa.aspx?knMnuTipo=Tipo&knMnuCodTipo=" + lnkId.ToolTip);
}
```

Comment: Quando você utiliza o botão do meio, automaticamente abre uma nova aba correto? Poderia explicar melhor o que você precisa?

Comment: O que esta acontecendo é que utilizo Response.Redirect() para abrir paginas, porém ela redirecionaria a resposta atual na guia do navegador atual, mesmo clicando com o botão do meio ou direito. O caminho é incluir o " href " na tag " LinkButton ".

Comment: Você pode utilizar o evento OnClientClick ou o controle asp:HyperLink

OnClientClick="window.open('OtherPage.aspx', 'PageName');"

Comment: Pessoas que codificam para o botão do meio do mouse são inimigas de quem usa um touchpad de laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o evento OnClientClick ou o controle asp:HyperLink

```
OnClientClick="window.open('OtherPage.aspx', 'PageName');"
```

Comment: Resolvi de outra forma, mas obrigado pela ajuda, código que utilizei : 

`<asp:LinkButton ID="LknMenu" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NOMTIPPRO").ToString()%>' ToolTip ='<%#Eval("CODTIPPRO").ToString()%>' 
href='<%#"KnPesquisa.aspx?knMnuTipo=Tipo&knMnuCodTipo=" + Eval("CODTIPPRO") %>'>`

Answer (score 0):

**Resolvido !!!**

Segue código utilizado.

Aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ListaMenu" runat="server" >
                                     <ItemTemplate>                                      
                                                <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LknMenu" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NOMTIPPRO").ToString()%>' ToolTip ='<%#Eval("CODTIPPRO").ToString()%>' 
                                                         href='<%#"KnPesquisa.aspx?knMnuTipo=Tipo&knMnuCodTipo=" + Eval("CODTIPPRO") %>'>
                                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                                </li></ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```